# AWS Routing Between Subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have two VPCs, call them A and B. A has two subnets, A1 and A2. B has one subnet, call it B1. I would like any traffic from A1 to A2 to first be routed to VPC B to be inspected by a [Cisco ASA](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/asa-firepower-services/index.html). So if I want an instance in A1 to communicate with an instance in A2 the route would look like this...

subnet routing A1->B1->A2

vpc routing    VPC A -> VPC B-> VPC A

I'm looking at the Route tables and I see that the first rule is...

Destination                     Target

'vpc cidr'                       'Local'

Which is not allowing any traffic to leave the VPC. I can't remove this rule. Is there a way to overcome this to force all traffic between any subnet in a VPC to first go through a peered transit VPC?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Avoid using "other" subnet. What is an ASA?

Comment: @helloV Sorry about that, I cleared up the language a bit. Also, I was referring to a Cisco ASA (intrusion detection device).

Comment: It is not `subnet cidr Local`, it is `vpc cidr local`. The local VPC traffic will not leave the VPC. Only the non-VPC traffic can be routed out.

Comment: I don't think you can do this right now. You'd have to either rely on VPC flow logs for the information you're seeking, or perhaps move subnet A2 into a different VPC C so that you could route from A to C via B, or use host-based IDS/IPS agents.

Comment: @jarmod This is what I feared, unfortunately VPC flow logs don't give layer 7 inspection. The one vpc per subnet route may work but I'm concerned that I may hit a hard limit for the number of vpc's per region. I know currently the soft limit is set to 5.

Comment: There is a reason why the intra-vpc traffic is routed local, otherwise it will be a routing mess. What you are asking is not possible.